# The subscription status of the object could not be changed

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I have set up a transactional replication then I'm tying to generate new snapshot but this error is appearing:

Error messages:

> Message: The subscription status of the object could not be changed.  Command Text: sp_MSactivate_auto_sub Parameters:    @publication = Web to Interserver   @article = %    @status = initiated

Please help me solve this problem. I already tried to drop the subscription but this error is appearing also.

Answer (score 0):

For all those searching an answer, I have resolved my problem by following this method:
http://www.dbaservice.lt/en/blog/mssql-administration/transactional-replication-the-subscription-status-of-the-object-could-not-be-changed-source-mssqlserver-error-number-14068/